# MongoDB Java API 3.0 closing cursor

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I'm getting a problem with my MongoDB Java Driver, 3.0 Version. After performing several operations over several collections (updateOne, find), I'm getting a `Command failed with error 8: '24: Too many open files'` error. A typical operation that I perform oftenly in my code is the following one:

```
private Document findFirst(int i) {
    FindIterable<Document> cursor = collection.find(new Document("_id", i)).limit(1);
    Document exists = null;
    for (Document doc : cursor) {
        exists = doc;
        break;
    }
    return exists;
}

Document exists = findFirst(integer);
return exists != null ? new MongoDBDocument(collection,exists) : null;
```

and, when I lookup for IDs, the "session" is not closed:

```
Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
for (Document k : collection.find().projection(new Document("_id",1))) { //Fully scan the collection
    s.add(Integer.valueOf((String)k.get("_id")));
}
return s;
```

So, I saw that in the elder APIs the result of the find operation returned a DBCursor that had to be closed. It seems to me that with the current implementation, no cursor is closed. The only way I see to get this to work is to close each time the MongoClient, but most probably I'm not doing somthing in the right way. Probably, when I retrieve collections with `db.getCollection(name)`, I have to close it somehow after performing some operations over it: I tried to read the documentation but nothing helped me.

The detailed error returned by the server's log is the following one:

```
2016-04-24T13:20:32.839+0200 E STORAGE  [conn721] WiredTiger (24) [1461496832:839907][968:0x700000934000], WT_SESSION.create: /data/db/index-1232-7182838846905439482.wt: Too many open files
2016-04-24T13:20:32.840+0200 I COMMAND  [conn721] command alledges.$cmd command: createIndexes { createIndexes: "2071853587", indexes: [ { key: { _id: 2071853587 }, name: "_id_2071853587", ns: "alledges.2071853587" } ] } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 exception: 24: Too many open files code:8 numYields:0 reslen:83 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 539ms
```

Where am I wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the current WiredTiger implementation. Running the server with this configuration solves the problem:

```
mongodb --storageEngine mmapv1
```

Answer (score 2):

This error normally related to having too many opened file descriptors. See [ulimit references](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/) to review and recommended settings. You also need to check the limits imposed on the process itself (not necessarily your system wide setting). See [proc-file-system](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#proc-file-system).

In regards to WiredTiger, there's a "sweep" thread that periodically closes open tables that have been idle for some period of time. Because the sweep thread acts based on idle time, not number of open file descriptors, WiredTiger won't respond to having a lot of files open at any particular time.

Another thing to check is how do you utilise the [MongoClient](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html) instance. Note that `MongoClient` transparently does connection pooling and generally you should only have one instance per JVM process. If you heavily create instances of this class you may acquire too many connections before they can be released (idle connections).

In regards to cursor, Although the server will eventually time it out, it would be more efficient to close a cursor yourself. Especially if the cursor has not been fully exhausted and no longer required. For an example you can close cursor:

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();
try {
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

For an extra tip, you can also utilise `.first()` to replace your `findFirst()` method, for example:

```
FindIterable<Document> cursor = collection.find(new Document("_id", i);
return cursor.first()!=null;
```